Proper configuration of partitioned producer and concurrent consumers with Spring Cloud Streams and RabbitMQ super stream
We have a Spring Boot 3.3.0 + Spring Cloud Streams + RabbitMQ binder and are strugling with proper configuration of both partitioned producer and concurrent consumers.
Sample app we use:
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    private static final AtomicInteger ATOMIC_INTEGER = new AtomicInteger(1);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public Supplier<Message<Integer>> randomInt() {
        return () -> {
            Integer currentValue = ATOMIC_INTEGER.getAndIncrement();
            System.out.println("Generated: " + currentValue);
            return MessageBuilder.withPayload(currentValue)
                    .setHeader("partitionKey", currentValue)
                    .build();
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public Consumer<Message<Integer>> intConsumer() {
        return (Message<Integer> input) -> System.out.println("Received: " + input.getPayload());
    }

    @Bean
    public EnvironmentBuilderCustomizer environmentBuilderCustomizer(RabbitProperties rabbitProperties) {
        RabbitProperties.Stream streamProperties = rabbitProperties.getStream();
        return builder -> builder
                .addressResolver(add -> new Address(streamProperties.getHost(), streamProperties.getPort()));
    }

    @Bean(name = "customPartitionKeyExtractorStrategy")
    public PartitionKeyExtractorStrategy customPartitionKeyExtractorStrategy() {
        return (Message<?> message) -> message.getHeaders().getId();
    }

}

and application.yml:
spring:
  cloud:
    function:
      definition: randomInt;intConsumer
    stream:
      function:
        bindings:
          intConsumer-in-0: testconsumer
          randomInt-out-0: testproducer
      bindings:
        testconsumer:
          destination: super-smc
          group: smc-group
          consumer:
            instance-count: 2
            instance-index: 0
            concurrency: 2
            partitioned: true
        testproducer:
          destination: super-smc
          producer:
            partition-count: 4
            partition-key-extractor-name: customPartitionKeyExtractorStrategy
      rabbit:
        bindings:
          testconsumer:
            consumer:
              container-type: stream
              super-stream: true
          testproducer:
            producer:
              producer-type: stream_async
              super-stream: true
              declare-exchange: false
  rabbitmq:
    host: <..>
    port: 5672
    username: <..>
    password: <..>
    stream:
      host: <..>
      port: 5552
      username: <..>
      password: <..>

We have two problems:

consumers are not consuming from the stream
producer does not use one of the partitions of the super stream (writes only to the first three partitions and skips the last one)

What are we missing or doing wrong?
We examined the current Spring Cloud Streams docs and Spring Cloud Stream RabbitMQ Binder reference guide but did not find the solution.
